# Determine FileSystem of USB Drive

Tags: filesystems, fat32

Is there a way to determine if a USB drive has been formatted as FAT, FAT32 or NTFS?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can plug it into a Linux box and figure out what is the device (dmesg), then something like fdisk -l [device] will print out the partitions and their types.

Comment: I was not sufficiently explicit. I need the answer to work with Windows XP or later. With USB drives formatted with the FAT filesystem, I am running into the limit of the max number of files you can have in the root directory. My program needs to verify that limit is not being reached before starting copy.

Answer (score 2):

use "mount" to show all mounted file systems. It shows the file system type and mount parameters.